# How to change font in unity game without source code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fonts

I am translating game, but i don't know how change font. I've tried search something in UABEA but I didn't understand anything.

I already translated all text in the game, but it looks so bad and goes beyond the bounds

Please help me where i can and how find fonts and replace it with my fonts

game: needy girl overdose

i don't have project in unity

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Unity by default has one font. You need to provide fonts in your assets folder. Then in your text object there's a font option.